# Excel does not recognize number cell after import from SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-import

I have an SQL table (well, stored procedure to be exact), which has values like this:

[image]

I import this data in Excel as:

> Data -> From Other Sources -> From SQL -> ... do the trick with
>   editing the SQL statement of the connection to look into the stored
>   procedure instead of View/Table -> Import Data -> Table

This works fine. The data is imported as:

[image]

Issue is, I can't `SUM` or `Average` (or any other math function for that matter) on those values! Something is wrong with them. When I copy such cell into another sheet I see this:

[image]

Excel does not recognize the field as a number. I have naturally tried the Cell -> Format -> Number/Accounting/Whatever... no success.

Any ideas

Edit:

Why isn't the following working:

[image]

Comment: If the stored procedure returns a *text string*, Excel can't do anything. Post the stored procedure or at least the types of the fields it returns

Comment: It's a text, indeed and I can't change it, because I have "rows as columns" approach there, no special treatment to any of them. Is there a way I can force Excel to format a given column as number? Updated my question.

Comment: Why are you copying the data anyway?  Just reference the table by name in your formulas and never have to do anything manual in your reporting again.

Comment: Excel now includes Power Query which allows you to transform the data you load, split or merge columns, apply formats etc

Comment: @iamdave - I only copy it to try to troubleshoot the issue. The core of the issue is - I can't `pivot` around this data, because I can't `SUM` for example, on those records.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the Power Query idea, this might work out!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - if you post this as an answer I will accept it, it seems to solve my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the stored procedure returns a string field instead of a numeric field. You can use Power Query to convert this to a number, or [apply any number of transformations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Shape-data-Power-Query-9b2dac2b-e13d-46a4-8940-7bc55f44597d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) like joining with other sources, splitting columns, formatting, pivoting etc.

Power Query is included in Excel 2016 or as a [free addin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379&CorrelationId=098e63ab-a6f5-4043-9243-3fe93b18e548) for Excel 2013